# How to get URL parameter with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, url, query-string

I would like to get an 'articlePageId' number from url as below, but the terminal window did not show the URL query parameters...

What's the matter with my coding?

Could anyone tell me how can I do that??

Thank you very much.

I have tried the following:

```
https://localhost:8090/articlePage.html?articlePageId='+item.ID

console.log(fullUrl)      // http://localhost:8090/
console.log(req.path)     // /
console.log(req.params)   // {}
console.log(req.query.articlePageId)  // undefined
```

Here is the Server

```
const express = require('express');
const expressStatic = require('express-static')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerObj = multer({dest:'./static/upload'});
const consolidate = require('consolidate');

const server = express();

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
server.use(multerObj.any());

server.use(cookieParser());
(function(){
const keys = [];
for(var i=0;i<1100000;i++){
 keys[i] = 's_' + Math.random();
}
server.use(cookieSession({
  keys,
  name:'sess_id',
  maxAge:20*60*1000
 }));
})()

server.engine('html',consolidate.ejs);
server.set('views','template');
server.set('view engine','html');

server.use('/',require('./router/web/index')());

server.use('/admin',require('./router/admin/index')());

server.use(expressStatic('./static/'))
server.listen(8090)
```

Here is the index.js

```
router.use('/', require('./articlePage')())
```

Here is the articlePage.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var urlLib = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring')

var db = mysql.createPool({
  localhost: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'blog'
})

module.exports = () => {
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') +req.originalUrl;
console.log(fullUrl)
console.log(req.path)
console.log(req.params)
console.log(req.query.articlePageId)
db.query(`SELECT * FROM articles_table WHERE ID='articlePageId'`, (err, page) => 
{
  if (err) {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('database error').end();
} else {
  res.send(page);
}
})
})
 return router
}
```

Comment: Could you show us configuration for express.js?

Comment: Sure, It's updated @Ivan Vasiljevic

Comment: @Sylvia Could you show your app.js ? the entry file of your app.

Comment: @Sylvia I mean the entry file on the server where you set up the app instance and start listening to requests, the whole express file.

Comment: It's updated. Is it correct? @Hamza Fatmi

Comment: @Sylvia yes thank you !

Comment: @Sylvia why you request `https://localhost:8090/articlePage.html?articlePageId='+item.ID` instead of `https://localhost:8090/?articlePageId='+item.ID` ?

Comment: cuz I get the error message and can not open the articlePage. html@Hamza Fatmi